# How to limit the type of characters input python

Tags: python, limit

How can I limit the number of characters and type of characters that can be inputted.

```
s = input('What is your number)
```

a number can only be 9 digits so it should be limited to 9 digits and only numbers

```
x = input('what is your email address)
```

an email address can contain a minimum of 8 characters and a maximum of 60 characters and also must contain an @ symbol.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can not limit the input while the user is typing. You will have to take the input, check it and reprompt if it fails the check.

Comment: How would I got about doing that>

Comment: check `len` of `s` and/or `x`

Comment: And how about the number the type of characters? Also, when I get the length what do I do with it?

Comment: How to do it? You will have to write code. Tell us if you get stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, my dear friend, you cannot limit input function, but you can achieve what you want by this way:

```
def isnumber(s):
    if s.isdigit() and len(s) <= 9:
        return True
    else:
        print('you should input number and length less than 9')
        return False

def main():
    s = input('What is your number')
    while not isnumber(s):
        s = input('What is your number')
    print("your number is", s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```